# TypeScript material-ui allow props not defined in @types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jestjs

I had a setup using React, material-ui, Flow, Jest doing snapshots in my tests.

In order to create consistent snapshots, i needed to define the ids in my material-ui components, otherwise they were autogenerated and different each time.

so i did this:
`<Card style = { style } id = { id ?`${ id }-card`: null }>`

this worked fine.  now i am switching to TypeScript, and have @types/material-ui.  Typescript is complaining about the id prop:

`[ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Card> ...`

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a way to suppress this? I know the component supports passing an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating `typings/material-ui/index.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace __MaterialUI
{
   interface SelectFieldProps
   {
      multiple?: boolean;
      selectionRenderer?: (values: any[]) => string;
   }

   namespace Card
   {
      interface CardProps
      {
         id?: string;
      }

      interface CardHeaderProps
      {
         id?: string;
      }

      interface CardTitleProps
      {
         id?: string;
      }

      interface CardActionsProps
      {
         id?: string;
      }

      interface CardTextProps
      {
         id?: string;
      }
   } 
}
```

and tsconfig:

`"include": [
      "./components/**/*",
      "./typings/**/*"
   ],`

this fixed my problems

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code for that definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c340b2e633af705e01a6837324879ee0dea8be2f/types/material-ui/index.d.ts#L780), it indeed does not support an `id` attribute.

If you believe this is an error, I would submit a pull request to DefinitelyTyped!